# TypeError: Cannot set property 'title' of null

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I'm new to nodejs and expressjs mongoose also, I'd encountered the error in these snippets.

/* POST edit category*/

```
router.post('/edit-category/:id', function (req, res) {

    var title = req.body.title;
    var slug =title.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();


    var id = req.body.id;


    var errors = req.validationErrors();
    if (errors) {
        res.render('admin/edit_category', {
            errors: errors,
            title: title,
            id: id
        });
    } else {
        Category.findOne({slug:slug, _id: { '$ne': id } }, function (err, category) {

            if (category) {
                req.flash('danger', ' Category Title exists , choose another.');
                res.render('admin/edit_category', {
                    title: title,
                    id: id
                });
            }
            else {
                Category.findById(id, function (err, category) {
                    if (err) {
                        return console.log(err);
                    }
                    category.title = title;
                    category.slug = slug;


                    category.save(function (err) {
                        if (err)
                            return console.log(err);
                        req.flash('success', 'Category editted!');
                        res.redirect('/admin/categories/edit-category/' +id);

                    });
                });
            }
        });
    }


});
```

TypeError: Cannot set property 'title' of null
    at D:\projects\cmscart\routes\admin_categories.js:142:36
    at model.Query. (D:\projects\cmscart\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:3407:16)
    at D:\projects\cmscart\node_modules\kareem\index.js:259:21
    at D:\projects\cmscart\node_modules\kareem\index.js:127:16
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:132:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:181:9)

Comment: What's the value of : `console.log(req.body) ` ?

Comment: but where i have used this

Comment: Add line: `console.log(req.body);` above : `var title = req.body.title;` . try to make a post request to that endpoint and show us the result.

Comment: { title: 'food3' } if i'll enter the value of title as food3

Comment: It is most likely coming from this line `category.title = title;` - will you add a `console.log(category)` line and let us know what `category` is?

Comment: category i sthe page schema consisting of title and slug as the entity

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
res.redirect('/admin/categories/edit-category/' +category.slug);
```

instead of

```
res.redirect('/admin/categories/edit-category/' +id);
```

and in **`edit-category.ejs`** (your edit page) above submit button
`<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<%=id%>">`